# Extra *(astericks) is displayed when entering encrypted password on cmd prompt

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption

I have below code to encrypt the user password, when user enter the password an * symbol is displayed on the cmd prompt. In below code, an extra asterisks is always displaced when I run the command. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

```
public static String readPassword(String prompt) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    EraserThread et = new EraserThread(prompt);
    Thread mask = new Thread(et);
    mask.start();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String password = "";
    try {
        password = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    et.stopMasking();
    return password;
}

class EraserThread implements Runnable {
    private boolean stop;

    public EraserThread(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        stop = true;
        while (stop) {
            System.out.print("\010*");
            try {
                Thread.currentThread();
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopMasking() {this.stop = false;}
}
```

i.e. an extra `*` is always displayed on the screen before entering the password.

Current Output :`Enter text to be encrypted:*`

expected output : `Enter text to be encrypted:`

Comment: Please always format the post, so people can read.

Comment: What's `Thread.currentThread();` for?

Comment: *You* are printing the asterisks, once every millisecond. Why?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667929/word-password-displays-in-asterisks-console-application).

Comment: whn i removed try {
                Thread.currentThread();
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            } Got the same output an extra asterisks. Please let me know why?

Comment: Please can some one tell why this extra asterisks is appearing on the console in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main highlight of the erasure thread is this statement - `System.out.print("\010*");`.

`\010` represents a backspace character. You could also use `\b`.

What the thread attempts to do is, after printing the prompt:

```
Enter password:
```

It will backspace/delete the last character, which in this example is `:` and then print a `*`. So the prompt will then look like this:

```
Enter password*
```

Every millisecond, it keeps doing the same. I.e. backspacing & placing a `*`. So, now the `*` that is printed, would get deleted and another `*` would be again printed in the same place. Which does nothing to final result - it's still the same. In fact it happens so fast that to us it looks static or like nothing is happening.

Once the person starts typing, e.g. `a`, it will look like this:

```
Enter password*a
```

Then after 1 millisecond the `a` gets deleted:

```
Enter password*
```

and a `*` is placed in its position:

```
Enter password**
```

This creates an illusion that what ever the user types is covered by `*`s. The actual string is obtained when we execute `readLine()`. If you want to see it happen in slow motion, you could increase the time to 1 second (1000ms).

I hope that explains to you why there's always an initial `*` in the prompt. One quick fix would be not to print anything at all. So the `sysout` would contain simple `\010` or `\b`. This would be like the linux or sql terminals where when one inputs password, absolutely nothing appears on the terminal until an enter.